# Async task getting called without selecting element of spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I am trying to call a Async task on selection of a element from android spinner but it is getting called even if I am not clicking on anything in Spinner. I think it is because of the first element is selected by default. 
The Async Task places a marker on a fixed Latlang.

```
private class Call extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.print("Entered");
            return "12.9265130, 77.6361550";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //super.onPostExecute(true)
            String latlong[] = s.split(",");
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
            LatLng buslocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(buslocation)
                    .title("Bus Location")
                    .snippet("and snippet")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        }
    }
```

The call for the async task in main activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        String colors[] = {"Select Bus for its Location","171","G3","356CW","600CF","600F"};

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                new Call().execute();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

            }

        });
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: where are you executing the AsyncTask?

Comment: @akash93 I am really sorry. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Set your selection to the first item without animation.

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)Util.findViewById(view, R.id.sound, R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(position, false);
```

This should ideally cause the `setOnItemSelectedListener`, but since no listener is assigned till now, it doesn't do anything. Next you set the `setOnItemSelectedListener`.

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

So all in all this should be the order.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)Util.findViewById(view, R.id.sound, R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(position, false);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

It seems like methods `setSelection(int position)` and `setSelected(int position, boolean animate)` have different internal implementation.

When you use `setSelected(int position, boolean animate)` with `false` animate flag, you get the selection without firing onItemSelected listener.

Answer (score 0):

Your spinner will select it's item in:

```
void layout(int delta, boolean animate)
```

Which is called from onLayout.

An easy solution here would be to simply override the onLayout method like this (in semi pseudo code):

```
@Overide
public void onLayout (args) {
   super.onLayout(args);
   Register your listener
}
```

Consider:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java#524